# Accessing arguments to llvm function attributes

Tags: clang, llvm

This question refers specifically to LLVM 3.9. Questions up front:

- **Do I need to do anything else to get a function attribute to take an argument?** I've included the changes to the LLVM codebase I've already made below.
- **Once the function attribute has an argument, how do I access that argument?** In my current solution, a new attribute is created, and the value accessed by my pass is wrong.

Previously, I've successfully added function attributes that take no argument, then applied them to functions in source code, and finally observed them in the LLVM IR as described [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html#how-to-add-an-attribute). I tried following advice given in [this thread](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2015-October/091122.html) on the llvm-dev list at llvm.org to add a function attribute that takes an argument. That thread also gives advice how to access the argument [here](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2015-October/091258.html). However I have not been able to get that technique to work in my code.

Here are the specific changes I made to my code:

In `$(LLVM_SRC)/tools/clang/include/clang/Basic/Attr.td`, I added the function attribute definition:

```
def DIMemberFunc : InheritableAttr {
  let Spellings = [GNU<"dimemberfunc">];
  let Subjects = SubjectList<[Function]>;
  let Documentation = [Undocumented];
  let Args = [DefaultIntArgument<"fid", 65535>];
}
```

In `$(LLVM_SRC)/tools/clang/lib/CodeGen/CGCall.cpp`, I added a manager:

```
void CodeGenModule::ConstructAttributeList(
  StringRef Name, const CGFunctionInfo &FI, CGCalleeInfo CalleeInfo,
  AttributeListType &PAL, unsigned &CallingConv, bool AttrOnCallSite){
    llvm::AttrBuilder FuncAttrs;
    llvm::AttrBuilder RetAttrs;
    //...
    if (TargetDecl) {
      //...
      if (TargetDecl->hasAttr<DIMemberFuncAttr>()){
        auto myattribute = TargetDecl->getAttr<DIMemberFuncAttr>();
        FuncAttrs.addAttribute("myattribute");
        unsigned myargument = myattribute->getFid();

        FuncAttrs.addAttribute("myargument", llvm::utostr(myargument));
      }
      //...
    }
    //...
}
```

In `$(LLVM_SRC)/tools/clang/lib/Sema/SemaDeclAttr.cpp`, I added a handler function:

```
static void handleDIMemberFuncAttr(Sema &S, Decl *D, const AttributeList &Attr){
  uint32_t fid = DIMemberFuncAttr::DefaultFid;
  if (Attr.getNumArgs() && !checkUInt32Argument(S, Attr, Attr.getArgAsExpr(0), fid))
    return;

  D->addAttr(::new (S.Context) 
  DIMemberFuncAttr(Attr.getRange(), S.Context, fid
    Attr.getAttributeSpellingListIndex()));
}
```

Lastly, in one of my passes, I have the following code:

```
if (F.getAttributes().hasAttribute(AttributeSet::FunctionIndex, Attribute::DIMemberFunc)){
    //Print Function
    errs() << "Found member function named: ";
    errs().write_escaped(F.getName()) << '\n';

    //Print the DIMemberFunc argument value
    int myfid;
    if(F.hasFnAttribute("dimemberfunc")) {
          myfid = F.getFnAttribute("dimemberfunc").getValueAsInt();
      }
    errs() << "\twith function ID: " << myfid << '\n';
}
```

When I run the pass, I get only partial success. Even though I set the functions' attribute argument to an increasing counter beginning at 1, I still get outputs as such:

```
Found member function named: _ZN8simple_t8getValueEv
with function ID: 0
```

The LLVM IR has the following attribute data for this function:

```
attributes #5 = { dimemberfunc nounwind uwtable "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "myargument"="2" "myattribute" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-jump-tables"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
```

*Any insights on how to get the argument directly from the attribute or links to better documentation than the mailing list post are appreciated.*